# Ionic - Ionic Pages

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I want to create a UI in the Ionic Framework sort of Android Fragments.
The header will have buttons etc which have animations. That's why I cannot use `navctrl.push` or `navctrl.setroot`. I need to change only the content of `ion-content` (MainPage) and load a new Page which contains only `ion-content`.
Below is a picture that presents how I would like to do it.

Are there any possibilities to do it?

[image: Picture]

**app.html**

```
<ion-header>
    <ion-navbar>
        <ion-title>Blabla</ion-title>
        <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="home()">Home</button>
        <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="second()">Second</button>
    </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>
<ion-content>
</ion-content>
<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
```

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform, NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { SecondpagePage } from '../pages/secondpage/secondpage';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController;
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
    });
  }

  home() {
    this.nav.setRoot(HomePage);
  }

  second() {
    this.nav.setRoot(SecondpagePage);
  }

}
```

In `HomePage` and `SecondPage` I put only `<ion-content>Test1</ion-content>` and `<ion-content>Test2</ion-content>`.
Now I have that situation - the header "covers" the rest. So I don't see any text because it's below the header. How can I change that behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure. You can have named [NavControllers](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/)

app.component.ts

```js
import {MainPage} from 'main'

@Component({
  template: '<ion-nav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
class MyApp {
  // First page to push onto the stack
  rootPage = MainPage;
}
```

main.component.ts

```js
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
   template: `
     <ion-header>{{ YOUR HEADER }}</ion-header>
     <ion-content>
       <ion-nav #yourNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>
     </ion-content>
   `
})
export class MainPage {
   @ViewChild('yourNav') nav: NavController
   public rootPage: any = StartPage;

   public goSomeWhere() {
     this.nav.push(SomeWhere);
   }

   public goSomeWhereElse() {
     this.nav.push(SomeWhereElse);
   }
}
```

Comment: It will open new page as a child of navroot. So animation which started in Rootpage wouldn't be continue on the second page.
Header cannot be opened twice, just only once. Ion-content can be changed etc.

Comment: No, it will not. Use `MainPage` for the root of the `ion-nav` in your `MyApp` component. Or any other way. The trick is to *know* that you can have different nav controllers and just use them in sub views instead of the main/root nav controller. My Source Code is an illustration, not a copy & paste solution.

Comment: I created a component and there will be header with buttons and animations. How should I navigate these pages?
I see that you put @ViewChild('yourNav') nav: NavController, but I dunno if that compoment should be a Root or what?

Comment: I have updated the answer a little, but I'm a little lost about what you are asking. What do you mean, how? What exactly is your problem? What code have you tried? See the tutorial on navigation for a general understanding of how navigation works: http://ionicframework.com/docs/intro/tutorial/navigation/ and then actually read the docs I have posted in the response.

Comment: @Ace That's a completely different questions now, though. Please accept the answer and post another question. You need to put the ion-nav into the ion-content, otherwise it won't work.